# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: in mysql

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Hi I have created jdbc program and database is MySQL 5.1
Also all my friends using same database for connection. Total number of connection became 150 from all of us.
So when i want to connect more then i got the following error

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

How to resolve this error.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: Increase number of connections or lose some friends - whatever's easier.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by increasing number of connection

set @@global.max_connections = 1250;

Have a look on the below link
http://www.netadmintools.com/art573.html

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you haven't create the databases or tables in the databases.
Please check the reason behind "Could not create connection to database server."

I have met this error, because I didn't create the database.

Answer (score 1):

when you make a connection from higher  versions of android version 9 to a mysql server you must always allow connections through:

```
if (Constants.VERSION_SDK > 9) {
      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
      StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you've forgot to setup the environment variable for MySQL in your OS.